# Timeseries - How are the window/span size and 'frac' in LOWESS related?

Tags: regression, time-series, smoothing, weighted-regression, loess

Many software implementations of locally weighted scatterplot smoothing (LOWESS), such as those in Python and R, require a *frac* parameter as an input. I am confused as to how *frac* is mathematically related to the term 'window size'.

According to [Statsmodels' documentation](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.nonparametric.smoothers_lowess.lowess.html),

> The algorithm works by estimating the smooth y_i by taking the frac*N closest points to (x_i, y_i) based on their x values and estimating y_i using a weighted linear regression.

The term 'window size' or 'span size' is often used to describe the span of data about which the locally weighted regression is performed. However, I found that while 0 < *frac* < 1, window sizes/widths are generally specified as > 1. For [example](https://www.mdpi.com/1996-1073/14/18/5841):

> Therefore in this work, we set the window width [of the] filter to 20.

In the context of time series analysis, what is the mathematical relationship between *frac* and *window size*?

Comment: I would have thought both would lead to a particular number of points being used for the local calculation, and this might with be stated either as the window or as a fraction of the total data.

Comment: The answer is contained entirely within your question. "frac" represents a *fraction of the points*, for which the width of the interval to contain them will depend on the local density (high density $\implies$ narrow interval to get the requited fraction of the points, low density $\implies$ wide interval), while normally a window width will be expressed in data units and may cover a varying fraction.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. @Glen_b, if I understood correctly, does this necessarily imply that frac = 1/(window_size), i.e., a window size of 20 corresponds to a frac of 1/20?

Comment: Not if I am understanding it correctly, no. Consider a variable $X$ with support on (0,300), but where (0,50) has half of the total the probability (uniformly on that interval) and [50,300) has the remaining half of the probability (also uniformly). Then a window of width 20 will have a higher *frac* within that first section than than if it was in the later section.

Comment: @Glen_b Okay, got it. This implies the relationship between window width and frac might depend on the autocorrelation and the probability density of the random variable/process __*X*__. But I was looking to translate the window width into a _frac_ value via some analytical/numerical relationship as research papers, such as the one in the example in the question, often mention the window width rather than the _frac_ value.

Comment: If we define the window size as the number of data points considered in a moving/stationary window, my initial intuition suggested that _frac_ = window_size/total_number_of_data_points. But I guess this doesn't explain the variation of _frac_ with probability distribution/density.

Comment: I didn't realize this was a time series question; I assumed it was a regression issue. (1) Are your observations are regularly spaced in time?  (2) is time your x-variable?

Comment: @Glen_b Yes, the question is on time series analysis; I've modified the question to reflect this as well. (1) Yes. (2) Yes, I'm smoothing the data with time as the x-variable.

Comment: If you data are regularly spaced, then naturally, a fixed width and a fixed frac correspond. But beware the issues of regression-like models on time series, of which there are several. Spurious correlation is one.

Comment: @Glen_b Oh, okay. So for fixed-spacing time series, does **_frac_ = window_size/total_number_of_data_points** hold true or is there a different relationship between _frac_ and window_size?

Comment: Presumably but you'd have to check either the documentation or the references (if it has any, python documentation isn't always great on that score) to see exactly how it was defined.

Comment: @Glen_b Well, neither the [R documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gplots/versions/3.1.3/topics/lowess) nor the Statsmodels docs relate window width to _frac_. Looking up Google Scholar, I found that only a small fraction of papers describe LOWESS with 'window width' (>1) rather than 'span' or 'frac' (both <1). I guess I'd need to contact one of the former's authors for clarification.

Comment: I did not suggest that either documentation would relate 'width' to 'frac', but that they (or their references) would define their terms, making it possible to be certain how they then relate. Without an explicit definition we'd be left to guess.

Comment: @Glen_b I mailed one of the authors of a paper different to the one in example in the question for a clarification. All I received in reply was a code snippet, with the frac value specified as 1/(window_size). I hope I'd receive a better response from an author of the other papers I've mailed.